# "The Server is not configured correctly" message while playing movie in iphone

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play video files from iPhone media player in my iphone application.I am reading the stream from one Media server.
but i am getting error message as "The server is not configured correctly".

Here is my observation:

-> I kept five different video files on server.(i am sure that all of these files are properly encoded and in right format.)

-> When i try to run same video URL in Mobile Safari i works perfectly without any error.

-> When i try to run any of video it doesn't create any stream on media server.(Usually when i try to play video it create stream on media server.but here the stream is not created on server side.)

-> I tried to play this files using Apple's sample application MoviePlayer but i am facing same issue.(Here i tried to run the application on Simulator)

-> I also checked on my iphone 2G having OS 3.1.2 (jailbreak) but i face same issue.

Please let me know your response on this.

Thanks,

Jim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out the solution.Actually for some links that i am getting from Server contains bad characters so the URL wasn't right one.

After correcting that issue now i am unable to play all the video file from media server.

Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions.

Thanks,

 Jim.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need a web server which supports progressive downloads. Apache does support it. 
Maybe you want to try the same scenario with the videos hosted on apache.

If that does not work, do post your code.